# Do I need a transit visa for my Ankara-Istanbul flight?

Tags: visas, transit-visas, turkey

This question may seem like a duplicate but I needed bit of help based on my situation. I am a Pakistani and I'll be travelling from Moscow to Cairo on 17 July. If I chose to travel with Turkish Airlines (the cheapest) I'll have a layover of 5 hours in Ankara, catch a domestic flight to Istanbul, have an 11-hour layover there, and then proceed to Cairo. Can I complete my flights without passing passport control? I do not meet conditions for e-visa and do not have enough time left to apply for a Turkish transit visa.

Comment: I don't know about Turkey in particular, but it is very unlikely that you can get on the domestic flight without a visa for Turkey (provided that you would normally need one when entering Turkey for touristic reasons). When arriving from a domestic flight, you can normally leave the airport without any additional checks, so I would be surprised if this concrete connection would be an exception to this rule.

Answer (score 4):

For the outlined itinerary, you would need a visa to enter Turkey in order to arrive in Ankara and connect with a domestic flight to Istanbul (and, from there, onward to Cairo). Without a visa for Turkey, you would be unable to board the Ankara-bound flight in Moscow.

Transit Without Visa (TWOV) could be an option, but only if you arrive and depart from the same airport and remain airside.

The information below is sourced and provided by the International Air Transport Association (IATA).*

> [**Visa & passport information**](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/find-visa-requirements-results.aspx?NC=PK&NV=Pakistan&DC=EG&DV=Egypt&TC=TR&TV=Turkey&h=aa30d762f2547dd72bcb6ef95016e7786428672c)
>
> Passport holder of Pakistan
>   Destination Egypt
>   Transit countries/territories   Turkey
>
> Destination - Egypt (EG)
>   **Passport**
>   Passport required.
>
> **Document Validity:**
>   Passports and other documents accepted for entry must be valid for a minimum of 6 months from the arrival date.
>   **Admission and Transit Restrictions**:
>   Nationals of Pakistan must hold return/onward tickets.
>
> **Visa**
>   Visa required.
>
> **Visa Exemptions:**
>   Nationals of Pakistan who are spouses and children of Egyptian nationals.
>
> - Accepted proof of Egyptian nationality is: (copy of) a birth certificate, passport or national ID card of the relative.
>
> Sons and daughters born to an Egyptian father.
>
> - Accepted proof of Egyptian nationality is: (copy of) a birth certificate, passport or national ID card of the relative.
>
> Sons and daughters of an Egyptian mother if born after 25 July 2004.
>
> - Accepted proof of Egyptian nationality is: (copy of) a birth certificate, passport or national ID card of the relative.
>
> **Warning:**
>   Passengers with a passport with gender "X" must have confirmation that their entry has been approved before departure by the Ministry of Interior.
>
> **Transit - Turkey (TR)**
>   **Visa**
>   Visa required.
>
> **TWOV (Transit Without Visa)**:
>   Passengers with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country within 24 hours. They must stay in the international transit area of the airport and have documents required for the next destination.

*Courtesy of [Emirates web site](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/find-visa-requirements.aspx) sharing of the tool.